# Allow inserting Stack Snippets into profile "About Me" section

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stack-snippets

I think allowing Stack Snippets on the profile page could be a nice addition.

I remember someone saying that profile pages are not visited too frequently, so I don't think this would bring up a huge security issue, a lot of freedom is given already.

Comment: Why would I need to show code in my profile?

Comment: @j08691 I imagine the intention would be to show off a bit with some dynamic client side functionality to play with. There are already profiles that try and do some quite complex interactive stuff with links to server side scripts and dynamically generated images for example.

Comment: @j08691 You could just show off a piece for code that you think is interesting and allow people to play with it, or just as a way to have a small box on your profile that you can easily customize.